# How can I serialize the OneToOneField to be list in Django-Rest-Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How can I serialize the OneToOneField to be list?

I have two Model:

```
class SwitchesPort(models.Model):
    """
    SwitchesPort
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    profile = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class Server(models.Model):
    ...
    switchesport = models.OneToOneField(to=SwitchesPort, related_name="server", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)
```

You see, they are OneToOne relationship.

In the SwitchesPortSerializer, I only can set the `physical_server` `many=False`:

```
class SwitchesPortSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """
    SwitchesPort
    """
    server = ServerSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
       ...
```

If I set True there will reports error, because they are one to one relationship.
The result will be like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "switches_port01",
        "profile":"",
        "server": {
            "name": "server01",
            ...
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

But, I want to get the `physical_server` as a JSON list, not the JSON object, how can I do that in Django-Rest-Framework?

My requirement data is like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "switches_port01",
        "profile":"",
        "server": [
            {
            "name": "server01",
            ...
            }
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

Although the relationship is one-to-one, I still want to get the list, not the object.
Is it feasible to get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `to_representation` method from serializer class

```
class SwitchesPortSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """
    SwitchesPort
    """
    physical_server = ServerSerializer(read_only=True)

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ret = super().to_representation(instance)
        ret['physical_server'] = [ret['physical_server']]
        return ret
```

Comment: For me   "ret.update(ret.pop('physical_server'))" worked. It pops physical_server address from red and updates it with all the keypairs of the popped "physical_server"